# Vuetify: Switch logo image based on theme

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a dark and a light theme on my project, in the dark theme I have a white logo image and I want to switch to a colored logo image when I switch to the light theme.

Here's my code for the theme :

```
    vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          txtWhite: '#FFFFFF',
          back1: '#141627',
          back2: '#181B31',
          back3: '#292B3D',
          logo: ['~/assets/logo_white.png'],
        },
        light: {
          txtWhite: '000000',
          back1: '#B0BEC5',
          back2: '#CFD8DC',
          back3: '#ECEFF1',
          logo: ['~/assets/logo_color.png'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

And here's my navbar where the logo is :

```
<v-app-bar clipped-left app color="back2">
  <NuxtLink
    @click="$router.push('/')"
    v-if="$auth.loggedIn"
    tag="img"
    :src="require('~/assets/logo_white.png')"
    to="/"
  >
```

I tried putting `$vuetify.theme.currentTheme.logo` in the src or just `logo` but it doesn't seem to work, I must be doing something wrong.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `logo` from theme settings and try this:

```
<NuxtLink
    @click="$router.push('/')"
    v-if="$auth.loggedIn"
    tag="img"
    :src="$vuetify.theme.dark?require('~/assets/logo_white.png'):require('~/assets/logo_color.png')"
    to="/"
  >
```